# What is the mathematical relationship between parent and child frame in tf?

Tags: ros, transform, ros-kinetic, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am very confused by the coordinate frame in this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/tf#static_transform_publisher).

In this command line syntax

```
rosrun tf static_transform_publisher x y z yaw pitch roll frame_id child_frame_id period_in_ms
```

1. Does the value `x y z yaw pitch roll` represents the transform from `child_frame_id` to `frame_id`? Or the other way around?
2. And what is the relationship between `frame_id` and `child_frame_id`? What is the order of the yaw pitch row in the transformation? Which one is the correct relationship?

- *Extrinsic* rotation (occurs about the axes of the fixed coordinate system):

  - `child_frame_id = R(yaw) * R(pitch) * R(roll) * frame_id + [x,y,z]`
  - `child_frame_id = R(roll) * R(pitch) * R(yaw) * frame_id + [x,y,z]`
- *Intrinsic* rotation (occurs about the axes of a coordinate system XYZ attached to a moving body):

  - `child_frame_id = frame_id * R(yaw) * R(pitch) * R(roll) + [x,y,z]`
  - `child_frame_id = frame_id * R(roll) * R(pitch) * R(yaw) + [x,y,z]`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/338992/what-is-the-mathematical-relationship-between-parent-and-child-frame-in-tf?/) by [ignite](https://answers.ros.org/users/49351/ignite/) on ROS Answers with karma: 77 on 2019-12-02

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the documentation makes this pretty clear, see below.

http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Overview/Transformations

http://wiki.ros.org/Papers/TePRA2013_Foote?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=TePRA2013_Foote.pdf

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2019-12-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: -1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ignite](https://answers.ros.org/users/49351/ignite/) on 2019-12-02**:
Thanks for pointing to the document. But could you please (in question 2) let me know which one is the correct mathematical formula? I don't think the document is very clear on what is child. I mean, the `tf` is the transform from `child_frame_id` to `frame_if`? Or the other way around?

**Comment by [ignite](https://answers.ros.org/users/49351/ignite/) on 2019-12-02**:
Also, is the `roll, pitch, yaw` in this syntax intrinsic rotation or extrinsic rotation?

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2019-12-02**:
I believe you can do the leg work yourself to find out :-) its all there for you

**Comment by [ignite](https://answers.ros.org/users/49351/ignite/) on 2019-12-02**:
@stevemacenski I am trying to do it myself right now. But I was just hoping that someone who is an expert like you can point it out; that is the reason I ask to ROS community here. Also, I don't think the document is very clear, especially about rotation (Euler & quaternion) conventions. (I'm quite sure I will ramp up once I'm familar with ROS convention.) But to newcomers like me, perhaps, in my humble opinion, it would be much easier if we write down the mathematical equations in the document; because the math would say it all.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I believe this is a perfectly valid question still in 2022, and not immediately clear from the tf/tf2 documentation and papers or REP 103, due to lack of the "intrinsic" and "extrinsic" rotation in the terminology.

Firstly, verbal overview in http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Overview/Transformations states that

> "the rotation of the frame A in W's coordinate system."

which hints that rotation of A is represented in the external coordinate system of W, hence **extrinsic rotation**

Secondly, doing a bit reverse-engineering, one could see that

```
static_transform_publisher x y z yaw pitch roll frame_id child_frame_id
```

way of using static tf, calls the following lines: https://github.com/ros/geometry2/blob/c73b5939723db078c9bbe18523230ad54f859682/tf2_ros/src/static_transform_broadcaster_program.cpp#L80

```
tf2::Quaternion quat;
quat.setRPY(atof(argv[6]), atof(argv[5]), atof(argv[4]));
msg.transform.rotation.x = quat.x();
msg.transform.rotation.y = quat.y();
msg.transform.rotation.z = quat.z();
msg.transform.rotation.w = quat.w();
```

which in turn calls : https://github.com/ros/geometry2/blob/c73b5939723db078c9bbe18523230ad54f859682/tf2/include/tf2/LinearMath/Quaternion.h#L95

```
  /**@brief Set the quaternion using fixed axis RPY
   * @param roll Angle around X 
   * @param pitch Angle around Y
   * @param yaw Angle around Z*/
  void setRPY(const tf2Scalar& roll, const tf2Scalar& pitch, const tf2Scalar& yaw)
    {
        tf2Scalar halfYaw = tf2Scalar(yaw) * tf2Scalar(0.5);  
        tf2Scalar halfPitch = tf2Scalar(pitch) * tf2Scalar(0.5);  
        tf2Scalar halfRoll = tf2Scalar(roll) * tf2Scalar(0.5);  
        tf2Scalar cosYaw = tf2Cos(halfYaw);
        tf2Scalar sinYaw = tf2Sin(halfYaw);
        tf2Scalar cosPitch = tf2Cos(halfPitch);
        tf2Scalar sinPitch = tf2Sin(halfPitch);
        tf2Scalar cosRoll = tf2Cos(halfRoll);
        tf2Scalar sinRoll = tf2Sin(halfRoll);
        setValue(    sinRoll * cosPitch * cosYaw - cosRoll * sinPitch * sinYaw, //x
                     cosRoll * sinPitch * cosYaw + sinRoll * cosPitch * sinYaw, //y
                     cosRoll * cosPitch * sinYaw - sinRoll * sinPitch * cosYaw, //z
                     cosRoll * cosPitch * cosYaw + sinRoll * sinPitch * sinYaw); //formerly yzx
    }
```

This is the exact notation in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles#Euler_angles_to_quaternion_conversion, which is indicated as lab1-2-3 sequence, where lab frame is **fixed** during the rotation. Therefore, it seems that it's following **extrinsic rotation**

Furthermore, in REP103 (https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html#axis-orientation), it's mentioned that the rotation convention is *"fixed axis roll, pitch, yaw"*. Although, this does not make it immediately clear, since fixed axis could also be interpreted as rotation around a fixed axis of a rigid body.

A nice summary of the conventions used in similar 3d tools can be found in:
https://rock-learning.github.io/pytransform3d/transformation_ambiguities.html

---

Originally posted by [goksankobe](https://answers.ros.org/users/56999/goksankobe/) with karma: 41 on 2022-01-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3